# u-sql fails to handle null

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying out azure datalake, and tried to test u-sql on my test file.

this is my test script

```
@input =
    EXTRACT TagName     string,
            time        DateTime,
            valuee      float,
            Quality     int
    FROM "/MCVD/{*}/{*}/{*}/{*}/{*}/{*}/{*}.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1, nullEscape:"");

OUTPUT @input
    TO "/output/Test-query.csv"
    USING Outputters.Csv();
```

When running in datalake analytics, i get an error with the column valuee at line 56.

This is the content of line 56

```
"M32_Amp_FurnaceAluTemperatureTubeReference",2018-02-08T14:48:53.5780000,"",1
```

I understand that this is because the column holding the value is empty (its the first empty line in the file). I tried to use various NullEscape paterns, but it continues to fail.

I tried to extract the column as a string, which didn't produce any errors.

this is the error:

```
Vertex failed
Vertex failure triggered quick job abort. Vertex failed: SV1_Extract[0][0] with error: Vertex user code error.
 VertexFailedFast: Vertex failed with a fail-fast error
 E_RUNTIME_USER_EXTRACT_ROW_ERROR: Error occurred while extracting row after processing 56 record(s) in the vertex' input split. Column index: 2, column name: 'valuee'.
 E_RUNTIME_USER_EXTRACT_COLUMN_CONVERSION_EMPTY_ERROR: Failure when attempting to convert empty column data.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U-SQL supports [nullable data-types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/built-in-u-sql-types).  Simply mark them with a question mark after the datatype, eg

```
@input =
    EXTRACT TagName     string,
            time        DateTime,
            valuee      float?,
            Quality     int
    FROM [your input path]
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1, silent:true);
```

You can also suppress error rows with the `silent` switch of the extractor set to `true`.  I am however getting some different errors with your script and sample data.  Is that an accurate repro?

Comment: I lokked at the silent option, but as i am testing the dataflow i am quite interested in handling the missing values instead of just skipping them.
You might be correct, i was playing around and the error i posted might be from a slighty modified script.
Never the less, the questionmark behind the float did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when extracting from csv with values as "null" (without quotes) on my file. I expected nullEscape parameter's default null value would handle the extraction but it threw the null value conversion error.

Tough that may be due to my csv not having double quotes as quoting.

Using *nullEscape:"null"* parameter solved it in my case.